# Pre-amp/Mixer or USB Interface for vocals?

Tags: audio-recording, home-studio, preamp, voice-over, audio-interfaces

I am a newbie to studio recording (voice artist) . I have decided to purchase a condenser mic for my recording (audiotechnica). However, I am confused as to whether I should purchase a Pre-amp/Mixer or a USB Audio interface.

I have taken a look at these two-

mixer - [Behringer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005EHILV4)

USB A-interface - [Focusrite](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MTXU2DG)

I would like to know, What would be an ideal thing for me to purchase , a pre-amp/Mixer or an usb interface?  are the above 2 options any good?

Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 2):

Go with the audio interface.  The "mixer" borders on useless.  It is basically just a cheap interface with some near useless features worked in to it.  You are paying for unused features rather than an audio interface that includes a clean pre-amp and quality ADC.  You want an audio interface for your purposes.  The reason to go with a mixer would be if you needed to mix multiple inputs down to one line input, but you only need one line input, so a mixer is irrelevant.

(Note, there are some advantages to a mixer as a control surface, but it doesn't appear this particular mixer can be used as a control surface.)

Comment: thanks for clearing that up ! will go with the Interface

Answer (score 1):

AJ Henderson gives the correct answer, but to expand on terminology a bit:

Most interfaces will have pre-amps built-in, so there is no need for external hardware (excepting quality concerns).

Comment: Great point about clarifying that pre-amps are built in to the interface, not a secondary thing that is needed.  I intended that, but it wasn't as obvious as I could make it.